# Listview com itens ocultos no jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

Usando o mesmo conceito presente em http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-search.html

Gostaria de saber se é possível apenas listar os itens quando eu pesquisá-los no searchbox. Não quero que todos sejam exibidos no quando a caixa estiver vazia.

Answer (score 1):

Como segue na [documentação do jquery mobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/) , basta adicionar `data-filter-reveal="true"` , assim:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
```

Exemplo funcional no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cku7fusk/2/) aqui